# Guess the Disney song from the initials number 8

Tags: music

Guess the song from the initials of the lyrics.

Y T I A I S
A Y B S M P
I G I M B S
B S I C S
I T S O I M
H C T B S M T Y D K
Y D K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is

> Colors of the Wind from Pocahontas

Comment: OOOH I've been sniped, +1

Comment: To be fair, I have a list of disney songs up for these "Riddles"

Comment: Same, to be honest haha

Comment: Soz, I though El-Guest answered first

Answer (score 1):

Is this song

> Colo(u)rs of the Wind, from Pocahontas?

Comment: You're right again. I'm doing one more disney song then i'm doing some beatles' songs

Comment: BTW. What is the daily reputation limit

Comment: Daily rep limit is 200 from upvotes, unlimited when you consider accepted answers though

Comment: @WilliamPennanti, Wait, why didn't I get the accepted answer? I answered first. :|